# Relationship between eigenvectors of A and $A^{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to find a connection between the eigenvectors of A and $A^{2}$.
where A∈ M3(R)

I know that if λ is an eigenvalue of A then $λ^{2}$ is an eigenvalue of $A^{2}$ but this doesn't apply to eigenvectors. Any ideas how I can solve this?

Moreover, what would the eigenvectors of $A^{n}$ be?

Comment: Hint: $A^2v = A(Av)$

Comment: What is the nature of $A$?, for example $A \in M_{3}(\mathbb{C})$

Comment: yes, A is a 3 × 3-matrix but A∈ M3(R)

Comment: Generally, if $f(x)$ is an analytic function, then the eigenvector of $f(A)$ is the same as $A$. Moreover if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $A$ with eigenvector $v$, then $f(\lambda)$ is the respective eigenvalue of $f(A)$ with eigenvector $v$.

Answer (score 1):

In general each eigenvector$~v$ of $A$ for an eigenvalue$~\lambda$ is also eigenvector of any polynomial $P[A]$ of $A$, for the eigenvalue$~P[\lambda]$. This is because $A^n(v)=\lambda^n v$ (proof by induction on $n$), and $P[A](v)=P[\lambda]v$ follows by linearity.

The converse is not true however. For instance an eigenvector for $c^2$ of  $A^2$ need not be an eigenvector for $c$ for$~A$, or for $-c$, nor even a linear combination of eigenvectors for $c$ and for $-c$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $v_1$ be an eigenvector of $A$, and $\lambda$ the corresponding eigenvalue of $A$.

$$Av_1 = \lambda v_1 \implies A^2v_1 = \lambda Av_1 = \lambda^2v_1$$

This tells you that $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$ and that $v_1$ is it's the corresponding eigenvector

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that A is diagonalizable
If $V_λ$ is the eigenspace of A of the eigenvalue λ, and $W_{λ^2}$ is the eigenvector of $A^2$ of the eigenvalue $λ^2$ then:

- If -λ is not a eigenvalue of A, then $W_{λ^2} = V_λ$
- If -λ is an eigenvalue of A, then $W_{λ^2} = V_λ + V_{-λ}$

If A is not diagonalizable, this is not true in general, and I do not know any relationships between eigenvectors of A and $A^2$, except from **(1)**.

PROOF

The fact that A**v**=λ**v** implies $A^2$**v**=$λ^2$**v**, implies

$V_λ \subseteq W_{λ^2}$     **(1)**

because every vector in the first eigenspace is also in the second one.

$\mathbb{R} ^n$ = the direct sum of the eigenspaces of A, because A is diagonalizable.
Because, for every eigenvalue λ of A, its eigenspace $V_λ \subseteq W_{λ^2}$, then the direct sum of all eigenspaces of A must be $\subseteq$ the direct sum of all eigenspaces of $A^2$, which $\subseteq \mathbb{R} ^n $ (not equal because, even though we know that A is diagonalizable, there might still be some eigenvalues of $A^2$ which are not the square of an eigenvalue of A.

$$ dim(\mathbb{R} ^n) = \sum_{i=1}^{k}{dim(V_{λ_i})} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{k}{dim(W_{{λ_i}^2})} \leq dim(\mathbb{R} ^n) $$

Because $\mathbb{R} ^n = \mathbb{R} ^n$ then all the  other inequalities must be equalities.

So, for each eigenspace $W_{λ^2}$ of $A^2$, it’s equal to the direct sum of all the eigenspace of an eigenvalue which, squared, gives $λ^2$, so it’s equal to the direct sum of $V_{λ}$ and $V_{-λ}$.

**This proof was taken from “[Esercizi di geometria e algebra lineare](https://www.amazon.it/Esercizi-algebra-lineare-geometria-Mauri/dp/8808192520)” by Luca Mauri, Enrico Schlesinger**

Comment: @AlbertSchrödinberg edited it, thanks